# Exclude folders from Synology Backup Task

Tags: backup, archive, synology

In the *Synology Drive Client*, I am trying to exclude certain folders from the *Backup Task* in the *Backup Rules* tab. However, this page says "The filenames or filename extensions listed below will not be backed up:". Is there any way I can overcome this problem?

I am using DSM 7.1.

I'd like to backup my programming projects to my NAS, which I'm actively developing, where a lot of temporal folders are generated. I didn't necessarily want to create git repositories for these projects since many of them are just simple hobby projects. Do you have any suggestions or know best practices for this problem?

I have searched for this problem on a few portals, watched videos and checked the official Synology website, but not found any solutions.